# CSS overlay problems, showing a splash page over flash element

Tags: html, css, flash, iframe

Check out the link below, as you can see my overlay is hidden behind the flash element.  However, the blue bar with the 'Continue' button appears above everything.  Does anyone know what CSS changes I need to make so the overlay will appear above everything below it?  The background loads an iframe.  Thanks.

http://honr.it/s4j

I can't add wmode="transparent" to the embed tag, since I have no control over the page loaded in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you *need* to set the wmode of the Flash player to "transparent" in order for this to work. Along with that you need something like as your CSS:

```
#popup {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#flash-player {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Basically, the *z-index* property needs to have value lower than the popup.

Comment: Please reread the original post.  I am loading an iframe in the background, therefore I have no control over the embed tag or the css for that page.